# ConvertFrom-JSON Not returning records

Tags: json, powershell

I'm attempting to parse the following JSON:

```
StatusCode        : 0
StatusDescription : 
Content           : {123, 10, 32, 32...}
RawContent        : Content-Length: 10276747
                    Content-Type: application/octet-stream

                    {
                        "764411904": {
                            "abbrName": "SF",
                            "awayLosses": 1,
                            "awayTies": 0,
                            "awayWins": 0,
                            "calen...
Headers           : {[Content-Length, 10276747], [Content-Type, application/octet-stream]}
RawContentLength  : 10276747
```

However, when I `Convertfrom-Json` I'm not returning any records. This is my following script:

```
$request = 'C:\Users\mcmon\Desktop\Projects\Madden Exports\teams-42e.json'
Invoke-WebRequest $request | ConvertFrom-Json | select abbrName
```

And yes... this is for Madden exports.

Comment: Running `Invoke-WebRequest` against a file seems like the issue here, try using `Get-Content` in its place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @mjsqu mentioned, you need to use `Get-Content` instead of `Invoke-WebRequest`.  Use the `-raw` parameter to import the json as a string instead of an array of strings.

```
$filePath= 'C:\Users\mcmon\Desktop\Projects\Madden Exports\teams-42e.json'
Get-Content $filePath -raw | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Comment: That works... Although I'm still not getting the selection. Is it the way the JSON is formed?

Comment: You'd need to access the child property somehow, though it's hard to tell exactly how without seeing the original json.  Might need to be something like `(Get-Content $filePath -raw | ConvertFrom-Json).abbrName`, though there might need to be a few more child properties between the original object and abbrName.